# Hide Nav Bar on Main Page - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to hide Nav bar on the main-start page of my app. but want to make it display with a title and back button on the second page. This is something I did, but it appears on the main page too.

In App.xaml.cs, I used this:

```
 MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

In corresponding login page, I created this:

```
private async void LoginPage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
    }
```

When the user will click it'll take to the second page(login page).

Also, how can I change the color of the nav bar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the constructor of the page you want to hide the navigation bar, use the following code.

```
Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

To change the color of the NavigationBar, you can do this.

```
new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
{
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#000000"),
    BarTextColor = Color.White
};
```

Comment: Like Android, can it happen that I can just change colors from a file?

Comment: In Android, you can do it via your Theme, with <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item> and change as needed

Comment: You can add styles to resource dictionaries to style components. Take a look at [Xamarin Global Styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/) for how to correctly do cross platform styles

Answer (score 6):

As a bonus, you can also remove it via xaml:

```
<ContentPage ...namespaces... NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">...
```

Comment: And depending on one's needs, can even use binding to hide or show the navigation bar on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

In App.cs use

```
MainPage = new YourProjectNamespace.MainPage();
```

This will hide your navigation bar on your first page

Comment: If you show the first page without a wrapped navigation page, how will you show the nav bar on the second page?